# Read remote XBee I/O pin states

Tags: arduino, xbee

So I thought this would be simple, and I'm new to XBee so it may be, but I want to request a remote XBee to transmit its current I/O pin states to me, whether they be input or output.

Use case: The controller sends state to the XBee and XBee updates to match and then controller goes down. While controller is down, the user at the remote XBee toggles a switch that changes an I/O input pin state. The controller comes back up and needs to know of this change.

How can I request the I/O state from remote routers?

NOTE: Running in API mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digi has a [useful article](http://knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/Digital-and-analog-sampling-using-XBee-radios) in their Knowledge Base about configuring a remote device to send I/O samples on a periodic basis, or when inputs change.  You can use `ATIR` to set a sample rate, or `ATIC` to configure inputs to monitor for changes.  All samples go to the address specified in `ATDH` and `ATDL` address registers.

For a one-off sample, you can simply send a remote `ATIS` command.